# Connect socket to local address on device

Tags: android, sockets, localhost

I'm hanging out on this problem now for a while. I'm sending data from device to device over sockets on receiving side I have to send this data from socket to device itself. `localhost/127.0.0.1/10.0.0.2` or WiFi address doesn't work.

How can I send data from a socket to `localhost:port` on device?

```
try
{
    Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 1500);
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        if(is.available() > 1024){
            os.write(buffer);
        Log.i(TAG, "localSocket writing: " + buffer.length);
        }


        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocalSocketThread" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and my manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: data arrives on port 44444, now i want to forward the data through an socket to localhost. i have tried to connect to "10.0.2.2", "127.0.0.1", "localhost" and own wifi address with DatagramSocket and Sockets to this addresses. i know that they are the loopback addresses of the device, but how can i connect to them?

Comment: Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml` and your *full* method code. Trying one line does not constitute trying.

Comment: And your manifest? What permissions have you requested?

Comment: +1. That's a well-written question!

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending null to the address field:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(null, 1500);
```

Answer (score -1):

Seen at your code, as it is written, makes no sense, you read from the socket and immediately you test for available(). You just read from it so most probably it will return 0.

```
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
   // this is what makes no sense
   if (is.available() > 1024) os.write(buffer);
   // what you probably want to do is
   //  Even this test is not necessary because you already test in the while loop
   if (len > 0) 
   {
      os.write(buffer, 0, len);
      Log.i(TAG, "localSocket writing: " + len);
   }
```